# Can you get values off stack without pop?

Tags: assembly, x86

On x86, can you simply retrieve a value on the stack without having to pop it?  Such as through a MOV instruction?

Comment: Yes, you just make a mov relative to the stack pointer (SP/ESP/RSP)

Comment: MOV the DWORD value at [ESP] to a register, ADD 4 to ESP. Assuming 32 bit code.